# How to center content in a UIScrollView with contentOffset

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

This should be a VERY easy problem but I'm having trouble getting the desired result. I have horizontally scrolling UIScrollView with a width of 320. The width of its content is 5000. I'm trying to center the content with:

```
// 'self' is the UIScrollView
CGFloat newContentOffsetX = (self.width/2) + (self.contentSize.width/2);
self.contentOffset = CGPointMake(newContentOffsetX, 0);
```

I don't understand why this is not centering the content. Can you see something wrong with the calculations?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

I think you want:

```
CGFloat newContentOffsetX = (self.contentSize.width/2) - (self.bounds.size.width/2);
```

diagram:

```
|------------------------self.contentSize.width------------------------|
                         |-----self.width-----|
|-------- offset --------|
                                    ^ center
```

Comment: Sorry about the "self.width" confusion. That's a shortcut I added with a UIView catagory. Why are you using self.bounds instead of self.frame?

Comment: I suspected that `self.width` wasn't the problem—really, it's that you want to subtract that from the `contentSize.width`—but I used `self.bounds` out of habit.  `self.bounds.size` and `self.frame.size` should be the same; I tend to use `self.bounds` unless I need the origin-relative-to-superview that I get with `self.frame.origin`.

Answer (score 12):

Use below code:

```
CGFloat newContentOffsetX = (scrollView.contentSize.width - scrollView.frame.size.width) / 2;
scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(newContentOffsetX, 0);
```

Answer (score 11):

**Swift 4**

Scroll to center of content of `ScrollView`

```
let centerOffsetX = (scrollView.contentSize.width - scrollView.frame.size.width) / 2
let centerOffsetY = (scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height) / 2
let centerPoint = CGPoint(x: centerOffsetX, y: centerOffsetY)
scrollView.setContentOffset(centerPoint, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 2):

I created a simple UIScrollView extension with IBInspectable properties to center content horizontally and/or vertically. It works only when the scrollview content size is lower than the scrollview size.

Here's the Swift 5.2 code:

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable class CenteredScrollView: UIScrollView {
    @IBInspectable var verticallyCentered: Bool = false
    @IBInspectable var horizontallyCentered: Bool = false

    override var contentSize: CGSize {
        didSet {
            if contentSize.height <= bounds.height && verticallyCentered {
                centerVertically()
            }

            if contentSize.width <= bounds.width && horizontallyCentered {
                centerHorizontally()
            }
        }
    }

    private func centerVertically() {
        let yContentOffset = (contentSize.height / 2) - (bounds.size.height / 2)
        contentOffset = CGPoint(x: contentOffset.x, y: yContentOffset)
    }

    private func centerHorizontally() {
        let xContentOffset = (contentSize.width / 2) - (bounds.size.width / 2)
        contentOffset = CGPoint(x: xContentOffset, y: contentOffset.y)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not the best solution but might work for you

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    [self centerScrollViewAnimated:NO];
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withView:(UIView *)view atScale:(CGFloat)scale {
    [self centerScrollViewAnimated:YES];
}

- (void)scrollViewWillEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity targetContentOffset:(inout CGPoint *)targetContentOffset {
    *targetContentOffset = [self suggestedCenteredContentOffset];
}

- (CGPoint)suggestedCenteredContentOffset {
    CGSize imageSize = self.pickedImage.size;
    CGSize containerSize = self.zoomingScrollView.bounds.size;
    CGPoint result = self.zoomingScrollView.contentOffset;

    if ( self.zoomingScrollView.zoomScale * imageSize.width < containerSize.width )
        result.x = MIN((self.zoomingScrollView.zoomScale * imageSize.width - containerSize.width)/2, 0);

    if ( self.zoomingScrollView.zoomScale * imageSize.height < containerSize.height )
        result.y = MIN((self.zoomingScrollView.zoomScale * imageSize.height - containerSize.height)/2, 0);

    return result;
}

- (void)centerScrollViewAnimated:(BOOL)animated {
    [self.zoomingScrollView setContentOffset:[self suggestedCenteredContentOffset] animated:animated];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5+

```
@IBDesignable class CenteredScrollView: UIScrollView {
    
    @IBInspectable var isVerticallyCentered: Bool = false
    @IBInspectable var isHorizontallyCentered: Bool = false

    public func center(vertically: Bool, horizontally:Bool, animated: Bool) {
        
        guard vertically || horizontally else {
            return
        }
        
        var offset = contentOffset
        if vertically && contentSize.height <= bounds.height {
            offset.y = (contentSize.height / 2) - (bounds.size.height / 2)
        }

        if horizontally && contentSize.width <= bounds.width {
            offset.x = (contentSize.width / 2) - (bounds.size.width / 2)
        }
        setContentOffset(offset, animated: animated)
        
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        center(vertically: isVerticallyCentered, horizontally: isHorizontallyCentered, animated: false)
    }
    
}
```