# UIView doesn't center properly in UIScrollView with autolayout

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiscrollview, autolayout

I'm making an application where I need an x amount of custom `UIView` and place them in a `scrollView`. The layout of the `scrollView` and the `UIView` `xib` are set with `AutoLayout`. The result I'm getting now is this:

[image: First View is well centred in ScrollView]
**First View is well centred in ScrollView**

[image: Second View is wrong and has a lot of space in between]
**Second View is wrong and has a lot of space in between**

See my VC Code under here.

```
let sponsors = Sponsors.createSponsors() <-- Array

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    configureSponsors()
}

//MARK: Load the AddView in ScrollView
func configureSponsors() {

    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(CGFloat(sponsors.count) * self.scrollView.frame.size.width, self.scrollView.frame.size.height)

    for sponsor in sponsors {

        numberOfItems++

        let addView = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("AddView", owner: self, options: nil).last as! AddView
        addView.addDataToAddView(sponsor)
        addView.frame = CGRectMake(CGFloat(numberOfItems - 1) * scrollView.frame.size.width, 0, scrollView.frame.size.width, scrollView.frame.size.height)

        self.scrollView.addSubview(addView)
    }
}
```

And here is my UIView code:

```
//MARK: Outlets
@IBOutlet weak var backgroundImageView: UIImageView!

@IBOutlet weak var sponsorTitle: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var sponsorLogo: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var sponsorSubtitle: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var roundView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var playMusicButton: UIButton!

//MARK: Properties
var cornerRadius: CGFloat = 3.0

func addDataToAddView(sponsor: Sponsors) {

    backgroundImageView.image = UIImage(named: sponsor.backgroundImage)
    sponsorLogo.image = UIImage(named: sponsor.logoImage)
    sponsorTitle.text = sponsor.title
    sponsorSubtitle.text = sponsor.subTitle
}

override func layoutSubviews() {

    roundView.layer.cornerRadius = roundView.frame.size.width / 2
    roundView.alpha = 0.7
    roundView.clipsToBounds = true
}

//MARK: PlayVideo
@IBAction func playVideo(sender: UIButton) {
    //play music
}
```

I've already searched for the same problems. I found out that I have to use the [Pure Auto Layout Approach](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2154/_index.html). Should that mean I need to programatically set the constraints for the UIView? 
Many thanks,

Dax

---

Update:

Pictures for scrollView setup:

[image: Attributes Inspector]
[image: Size Inspector]

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15583515/how-to-center-content-in-a-uiscrollview-with-contentoffset

Comment: @BadalShah I've tried the suggest code to override the scrollViews `contentOffset` but I have same result.

Comment: how you setup scroll-view programatically or through storyboard ?  can you show me your constrain in storyboard?

Comment: @BadalShah Through storyboard, see update

Answer (score 0):

You should not perform layout calculations in `viewDidLoad` as frames are not set correctly till then.

Correct place to do this is either `viewWillLayoutSubviews` or `viewDidLayoutSubviews` as you will get the correct frame data when these functions are called

Comment: Good point, but has nothing to do with the problem I still experiencing